# Move constructor of unrestricted union crashes with invalid_pointer

Tags: c++, memory, move-semantics, unions, move-constructor

An example with unrestricted union class that holds either a map of ints or a vector of ints:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vec; 
typedef std::map<std::string, int> int_map; 

struct Vec {

  bool is_map;

  union {
    int_vec int_vec_val;
    int_map int_map_val;
  };

  // MOVE CONSTRUCTORS
  Vec(int_vec&& val)  : is_map(false), int_vec_val(std::move(val)) {
    std::cout << "move vec" << std::endl;
  }

  Vec(int_map&& val)  : is_map(true),  int_map_val(std::move(val)) {
    std::cout << "move map" << std::endl;
  }

  Vec(Vec&& rhs) : is_map(rhs.is_map) {
    if (is_map) {
      int_map_val = std::move(rhs.int_map_val);
    } else {
      std::cout << "Crashing now ... " << std::endl;
      int_vec_val = std::move(rhs.int_vec_val); // <--- how to do this correctly?
    }
  }

  // DESTRUCTOR
  ~Vec() noexcept {
    if (is_map) {
      int_map_val.~int_map(); 
    } else {
      int_vec_val.~int_vec();      
    }
  }
};

Vec gen_Vec() {
  Vec v1(int_vec({1, 2, 3}));
  return Vec(std::move(v1));
}

int main() {
  Vec v2  = gen_Vec();
}
```

This code crashes with `*** Error in ./tmp2: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400f6d ***` in the `Vec(Vec&&)` move constructor:

```cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 tmp2.cpp -lm -o tmp2 && ./tmp2
move vec
Crashing now ... 
*** Error in `./tmp2': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400f6d ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fba03ab47e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7fba03ac0ae8]
./tmp2[0x400d0d]
./tmp2[0x400a7c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fba03a5d830]
./tmp2[0x400af9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 13240011                           /store/Dropbox/dev/jamr/src/tmp2
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:11 13240011                           /store/Dropbox/dev/jamr/src/tmp2
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:11 13240011                           /store/Dropbox/dev/jamr/src/tmp2
006ce000-00700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fba03734000-7fba0383c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1065106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fba0383c000-7fba03a3b000 ---p 00108000 08:01 1065106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fba03a3b000-7fba03a3c000 r--p 00107000 08:01 1065106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fba03a3c000-7fba03a3d000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 1065106                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
```

My questions are:

1. What is the correct way to move those vectors and maps?
2. Is there a way to define `Vec(Vec&& rhs)` move constructor entirely in the mem initializer list?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need placement new.

Comment: @T.C I am using `new (&int_vec_val) int_vec(rhs.int_vec_val);` in my copy constructor, but that entails copying the vector AFAICU. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `int_vec_val = std::move(rhs.int_vec_val);` implies that `int_vec_val` denotes an existing, live object of type `int_vec` and you want to change its value by assigning to it. This is not the case: since the members of the anonymous union don't have default member initializers and don't have corresponding *mem-initializer*s either, no initialization is performed on them, so their lifetimes don't start.

This means that none of `int_map_val` and `int_vec_val` is alive when the constructor's block is entered. You have to actually construct a new object of the right type in the right place using placement new:

```
Vec(Vec&& rhs) : is_map(rhs.is_map) {
   if (is_map) {
      std::cout << "move contained map\n";
      new(&int_map_val) int_map(std::move(rhs.int_map_val));
   } else {
      std::cout << "move contained vec\n";
      new(&int_vec_val) int_vec(std::move(rhs.int_vec_val));
   }
}
```

The answer to your second question is: no, not really, since `rhs.is_map` is generally only known at run time and the contents of the *mem-initializer-list* needs to be known at compile time. However, in this case there's no problem with doing the initialization in the constructor's block (and no real benefit to be gained by doing it in the *ctor-initializer*), since no initialization is performed on the union members by default.

Comment: As a note, `Vec(Vec const&)` can be implemented via forwarding constructors, wholly in the initializer list, once you have the 3 ones the OP wrote  Simply `Vec(Vec const& rhs):Vec( rhs.is_map?Vec(rhs.int_map_val):Vec(rhs.int_vec_val) )`, and `Vec(int_vec const& Val):Vec( int_vec(Val) ){}` etc.

Comment: @Yakk Good note, it helps avoid code duplication. A good implementation should only generate one extra move construction for `int_vec` or `int_val`, which is no big deal. And even that could be avoided by duplicating just the implementation of the constructors from `const int_vec&` and `const int_map&`. Not having to write the whole `Vec` copy constructor is still a net gain.